# contour plot with date-time strings as x values

Tags: r, contour

I am trying to produce a color contour plot showing time along the x axis, depth along the y and temperature as the z values. Time is given as:

```
"2011-01-01 00:01"

i.e. "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

Is there a method for producing the color contour plot from these, and using

```
filled.contour(Time,Depth,temp)
```

example:

```
time <- c("2011-01-01 01:00", "2011-01-01 02:00", "2011-01-01 03:00",
    "2011-01-01 04:00")
depth <- seq(1,10,by = 1)
seq1 <-  seq(1:40)
temp <- matrix(seq1, 10)
```

Every column of temp represents a different time and every row represents a different depth.

Comment: I somehow miss the question or can't see what the problem is...

Comment: From the example above: filled.contour(time,depth,temp) produced an error :- Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
time2 <- as.POSIXct(time)
```

Result:

```
> time2
## [1] "2011-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "2011-01-01 02:00:00 EST"
## [3] "2011-01-01 03:00:00 EST" "2011-01-01 04:00:00 EST"
```

Now plot it:

```
filled.contour(time2,depth,t(temp))
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to do the same and tried using `as.POSIXct(c(2,4,7,10,14,21,30,60,90,120,180,365))` but get the following error `Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`. What can I do?

Comment: if your times are numeric in the first place, why are you trying to turn them into `POSIXt` or characters? Why not just leave your time variable alone follow the code above but use `filled.contour(time,depth,t(temp))` ?

Comment: I want the plot to be "sort of logarithmic" with equal spacing between each point. By doing what you just proposed, the 2, 4, 7, 10, 14 get squashed on the left.

Comment: I think you'd be better off posting a new question (with reproducible example, please); it wouldn't hurt to link back to this one.  You *might* be able to do this using `factor(your_var)`, but I haven't tried.