# Contour plot x-labeling

Tags: r, plot

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782600/contour-plot-with-date-time-strings-as-x-values/10783184?noredirect=1#comment36699155_10783184) question but I wish to write special values on the x-axis.
I have the following code:

> x <- c(1:12)
>   y <- c(1:12)
>   filled.contour(c(2,4,7,10,14,21,30,60,90,120,180,365), y, outer(x,y))

Gives the following plot :[image]

My problem is that I don't want the plot to be squeezed on the left but want all values in `c(2,4,7,10,14,21,30,60,90,120,180,365)` to be equally spaced on the x-axis.

How can I do this?
As an extension, how can I put characters `"two"`, `"four"`, ... instead of 2, 4, ... on the x-axis?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a start:

```
x <- 1:12
y <- 1:12
xvals <- c(2,4,7,10,14,21,30,60,90,120,180,365)
fx <- as.numeric(as.factor(xvals))
filled.contour(fx, y, outer(x,y),
               plot.axes= {
                   axis(2)  ## plain
                   axis(1,at=fx,labels=xvals)
               })
```

[image]

However, you can see that the '180' label is already getting omitted, which means that things are going to be even worse if you translate the x-axis labels into words (do you really want the last tick label to read "three hundred sixty-five")?  (You can use `par(las=3)` to turn the labels vertical, but that's ugly too.)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332463/convert-written-number-to-number-in-r) points us to `qdap::replace_number()`, but it doesn't seem to work for single-digit numbers ...

```
 library(qdap)
 filled.contour(fx, y, outer(x,y),
                plot.axes= {
                    axis(2)  ## plain
                    axis(1,at=fx,labels=replace_number(xvals))
 })
```

**update**: [the qdap maintainer has already fixed this bug](https://github.com/trinker/qdap/commit/a422b06440ac116e77ba2649db0cc09f8c3a88c4); if you need the latest version you could try `devtools::install_github("qdap","trinker")`

[image]

If you're in a big hurry you could just fix the result by hand.

Comment: Sorry for being so long. Great thanks! It works and I wrote "yearly" instead of "365" and so on. I gave `par(las = 3)` a try, indeed it's ugly and overlaps my x label. Is there a way I can make it diagonal? I tried other values of `las = ` but none seem to  work.

Comment: diagonal is harder, but if you look around you'll find it: googling "r diagonal axis text" got my several good hits, including a few on SO (actually this is an [R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f))